# Creating tiled pattern in curved wave

Tags: adobe-photoshop, vector, shapes, patterns, tiles

How Do I make something similar to following image in Photoshop?

[image]
(Click to see larger)

I thought of creating a curved shape by pen and then apply the tiled pattern to it but not sure how to create the pattern and spherical effect.

**I need the whole shape and its inside pattern vector.**

Thanks

Comment: Within 8 mins you have posted two questions in regards to patterns.

Comment: "_I need the whole shape and its inside pattern vector._"–Do you need the _output_ to be vector? Photoshop is not the best tool for that job.

Comment: @JohnB Actually not the final output, But I need it to remain vector in PSD file for further edits.